# Problem related with solution to the differential equation $y'=|y|^{\frac12},y(0)=0\,$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck on the following problem that says :

> Which of the following is a solution to the differential equation $y'=|y|^{\frac12},y(0)=0\,$ where square root means the 
>   positive square root ?
>
> 1. $y(t)=\frac{t^2}{4}$
> 2. $y(t)=-\frac{t^2}{4}$
> 3. $y(t)=\frac{t|t|}{4}$
> 4. $y(t)=-\frac{t|t|}{4}$

MY ATTEMPT: Taking $y>0,$ I get from the differential equation $y'=|y|^{\frac12},y(0)=0 \implies 2\sqrt y=x $. Now, after 
looking at the options ,I am not sure which of the aforementioned options is correct . Can someone help?

Comment: In what *interval*?

Comment: Unfortunately no interval has been mentioned in the question. So,it can be $(-\infty, +\infty)$ .

Comment: Check each $y$ in each subinterval $(-\infty,0]$, $[0,+\infty)$. And double-check $y'(0)$ (all/some the $y$s are differentiable in 0?).

Comment: Hint: Since $y' \ge 0$, the solution must be an increasing function. (That at least tells you that some of the options are incorrect; to verify that there really is a correct option you must compute a litte.)

Comment: the answer is 3

Comment: @HansLundmark thanks a lot sir for the valuable input. Got your point.

Comment: Why can't you just compute $y'$ and $|y|^{1/2}$ for each of the proposed answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redefine $y'$ without modulus into two functions into two intervals, solve every one try to put them in one form you will get the answer 3
$$y'=(-y)^{\frac{1}{2}}\to y=-\frac{t^2}{4}=\frac{t|t|}{4}\ \ \text{when $t,y\le0$}$$
$$y'=(y)^{\frac{1}{2}}\to y=\frac{t^2}{4}=\frac{t|t|}{4}\ \ \text{when $t,y\ge0$}$$

Comment: When answers are already proposed, it is usually easier to check them by just substituting into the ODE and see if it's satisfied, rather than solving the ODE and try to match the results.

Answer (score 0):

Only 3, is a solution.

But it is noteworthy, that this particular initial value problem does not enjoy uniqueness. Another solution of the same IVP is $y\equiv 0$ - In fact, this IVP has infinitely many solutions.